# Given two points, I need to find all of the 'sections' of the graph that the line segment travels through.

Tags: coordinate-systems

What do I mean by "sections"? Imagine a piece of graph paper. Each square bounded by integer horizontal and vertical grid lines is a "section", and is named after its lower left coordinate — (1,1), (1,2), etc.

Given two arbitrary points, that do not have to be integers, I need to find all of the 'sections' that the line segment made by connecting those two points travels through.

Comment: When you say "travels through", are you including boundaries, or just interior points?

Comment: @rogerl Only interiors. I do not need to know if it is tangent to a corner or something.

Comment: Although if it makes the math simpler, it wont harm anything if it does take into account boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your two points

$$\begin{align}
A &= (x_a, y_a) \\
B &= (x_b, y_b)
\end{align}$$

Then, the segment joining them is the set of all points $S(t)$ where

$$S(t) = ((1-t) x_a + t x_b,\quad (1-t) y_a + t y_b)$$

for all $0 \le t \le 1$.

From there, to enumerate the "sections", you can either enumerate all the integer $x$ values or the integer $y$ values.  The problem is symmetrical, but iterating over $x$ will probably feel more natural.

So, enumerate all integers $x_i$ between $x_a$ and $x_b$.

$$t_i = \frac{x_i - x_a}{x_b - x_a}$$

Since you want the lower-left corner, you want to take the floor of the $y$-coordinate.

$$S_i = \left(x_i, \left\lfloor (1-t_i)y_a + t_i y_b\right\rfloor\right)$$

Of course, if you have a vertical line where $x_a = x_b$, then you have to treat that as a trivial special case — just enumerate all the $(\left\lfloor x_a \right\rfloor, y_i)$ for all integer $y_i$ between $y_a$ and $y_b$.